# Android Notification if user is logged in

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app and I'm using Android Studio to do it. So I made this app and basically an admin can send "requests" to an user. You can log in the app as an admin or as an user and I made it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static Button b_connexion ;
    public static EditText et_identifiant ;
    public static EditText et_password ;
    public static String mdpInterprete;
    public static String mdpAdmin;
    public static InterpretesDAO unInterpreteDAO;
    public static AdminDAO unAdminDAO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        unInterpreteDAO = new InterpretesDAO(this);
        unAdminDAO = new AdminDAO(this);
        b_connexion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_connexion);
        et_identifiant = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_id);
        et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mdp);
        et_password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);


        b_connexion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("testId", et_identifiant.getText().toString());
                Bundle bundleATransmettre = new Bundle();
                bundleATransmettre.putString("id", et_identifiant.getText().toString());
                Intent intent_interprete = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuInterprete.class);
                Intent intent_interpretariat = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuInterpretariat.class);
                intent_interprete.putExtras(bundleATransmettre);
                intent_interpretariat.putExtras(bundleATransmettre);
                try {
                    mdpInterprete = unInterpreteDAO.getInterprete(et_identifiant.getText().toString()).getPASSWORD();

                } catch (NullPointerException e){

                }

                try {
                    mdpAdmin = unAdminDAO.getAdmin(et_identifiant.getText().toString()).getPASSWORD();

                } catch (NullPointerException e){

                }

                if(et_password.getText().toString().equals(mdpInterprete))
                {
                    et_password.setText("");
                    startActivity(intent_interprete);
                }
                else if(et_password.getText().toString().equals(mdpAdmin)) {
                    et_password.setText("");
                    startActivity(intent_interpretariat);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "L'identifiant ou le mot de passe est incorrecte", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And so as I said, when you are logged in as an admin you can send a request to a user and the user can see the list of requests that he received. I would like to send a notification to the user when he receives a new request and that then when he clicks on the notification, it goes to the activity where he can see all the requests.
But I don't know how to do it because I need to send the notification only if you are logged in as a user and even if you closed the app.

Can you help me ?

(sorry for my English, I'm french)

Answer (score 0):

Where the requests come from ? internet or localservice?
If is from internet,you need a server which sends the msg to client;
Whatever you must create a service to send notification if you want to notify user even if the app is closed.